# react native set state to text value from flatlist

Tags: sqlite, react-native, expo

In my react native app I have a sqlite storage solution and on this page I select a record from my table and use a flatlist to display the value, which works perfectly:

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.FlatListActivityItems}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.ListViewItemSeparator}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View key={item.id}>
            <Text style={styles.textUnderlines}>{item.activity} <Text style={styles.recordsTypes}>
                Minutes
            </Text></Text>
        </View>
    )}
/>
```

The problem is, I need to use the same value of item.activity in another place in this page as a data object which currently uses state

```
this.state = {activity: ''}
```

Is there a way on page load that I can just take the value `{item.activity}` and set it to the activity state so that I can use it anywhere else in the page with the state call?

Comment: there are several item.activity, which you want ???? the one which is clicked ???

Comment: If you are using a Flatlist it means you have more than one value of item.activity. Which one do you choose that needs to be used in the rest of the page?

Comment: I'm using a flatlist but there is only one value because the query limits it to 1. I'm only showing one value for display purposes and i need it set to state on load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So where you are getting the data of flatlist, just there get the value and setstate it like below

```
vartemp = this.state.FlatListActivityItems[0].activity
this.setState({activity:vartemp})
```

I hope this helps....Thanks :)

Comment: I need a way to set it on page load with no click though. It is just for display in this case, and even though it's a flat list, the query only returns one value so there will only ever be one item.activity. I just want the one being displayed to be set in state without needing a click